How to resolve "AVD Terminated"?
While starting the emulator, I get the following error: "AVD terminated".
I tried wiping the data, reinstalling AVD and reinstalling Android Studio.
Even after formatting the PC, it is showing AVD TERMINATED
In log file, I can see below message:
2024-09-23 15:57:27,895 [  19368]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API
   35 - C:\Users\prana\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe
   -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Medium_Phone_API_35 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300 

2024-09-23 15:57:27,973 [  19446]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 35 -
   Storing crashdata in:
   C:\Users\prana\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-35.1.21.db,
   detection is enabled for process: 7476 

2024-09-23 15:57:27,973 [ 
   19446]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 35 - Android emulator
   version 35.1.21.0 (build_id 12325540) (CL:N/A) 

2024-09-23
   15:57:27,973 [  19446]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 35 -
   Graphics backend: gfxstream 

2024-09-23 15:57:27,973 [  19446]   INFO
   - Emulator: Medium Phone API 35 - Found systemPath C:\Users\prana\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-35\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
   
2024-09-23 15:57:28,084 [  19557]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API
   35 - Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
   

2024-09-23 15:57:28,084 [  19557]   WARN - Emulator: Medium Phone API
   35 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515 

2024-09-23
   15:57:28,938 [  20411]   WARN -
   #com.android.sdklib.deviceprovisioner.DeviceAction - The emulator process for AVD Medium_Phone_API_35 has terminated.
   com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$EmulatorTerminatedException:
   The emulator process for AVD Medium_Phone_API_35 has terminated.     at
   com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$WaitForEmulatorTask.run(EmulatorConnectionListener.java:93)
    at
   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.RwLockHolder$executeOnPooledThread$1.run(RwLockHolder.kt:154)
    at
   java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at
   java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at
   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at
   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at
   java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at
   java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at
   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at
   java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

I wiped the data, reinstalled AVD and JDK, also reinstalled Android Studio. Still, the error persists.

try a different system image
